# Solving the quadratic formula to determine stability of a system

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratics

I am trying to solve the $2\times 2$ matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -k &-b \end{bmatrix}$$ for a relationship between the variables $k$ and $b$ to determine when a system is stable. Stability means that the real component of the eigenvalues are all $0$ or less.

I have sought the eigenvalues and have gotten to the quadratic formula here: eigens $= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4k}}{2}$

I know that the eigenvalues must be less than $0$, but I am having trouble with the algebra to get to a clear relationship.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Going off your formula for the eigenvalues:

If $b^2 - 4k \leq 0$, then the real part of the eigenvalues will be $-\frac{b}{2}$. So in this case, the eigenvalues will have real part less than $0$ if $-\frac{b}{2} \leq 0$, or, equivalently, if $b \geq 0$

If $b^2 - 4k \geq 0$, then the eigenvalues are all real numbers of the form:

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4k}}{2}$$

We always have that:

$$\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4k}}{2} \geq \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 -4k}}{2}$$

So it suffices to only check that $\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4k}}{2} \leq 0$

$$\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4k}}{2} \leq 0$$

$$\sqrt{b^2 - 4k} \leq b$$

Since we are considering the positive square root, this equation will never hold if $b$ is negative, so we assume $b$ is positive, allowing us to square both sides:

$$b^2 - 4k \leq b^2$$
$$-4k \leq 0$$
$$4k \geq 0$$

So your solutions: the eigenvalues have real part less than or equal to 0 if:

$b^2 \leq 4k$ and $b \geq0$

or

$b^2 \geq 4k \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$

Which simplifies to the condition: $b, k \geq 0$

Comment: At the very start the inequalities need not be strict.  And one can simplify the conditions to  $b,k \ge 0$. Note you have $0 \le b^2 < 4k$ *or* $b^2 \ge 4k \ge 0$. In a way the matrix is set up for the condition to be nice. But still nice work, in working it out.

Comment: Edits made! I completely missed that it simplified like that; it looks much nicer that way. Thanks!